# Error while redirecting to another page-Confirm Form Resubmission Error

Tags: vb.net

I have a page named a.aspx and clicking on the submit button i redirected to b.aspx with one parameter named fileid.

On clicking on back button from b.aspx i have to go to a.aspx.But now on clicking  back button, i got one error as follows

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>
> This web page requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed. Press Reload to resend that data and display this page."

What i have to do to resolve this?

i haven't used any codes.my problem is i cant return to the previous page by clicking the back button in Google chrome.In internet explore its working.

Comment: in Internet explorer,i can go back to my previous page.but when it comes to other browsers, the problem occurs

Comment: Can you paste the code which you use for the back button?

Comment: i haven't used any codes.my problem is i cant return to the previous page by clicking the back button in Google chrome.In internet explore its working.

Comment: Then where are thse a.aspx and b.aspx? U have not used any code means? U mean the browser button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lokks like this was an [existing issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2616) with Chrome and it was fixed last year. Check whether you are using the updated version.